# C# How to insert items at specific index in nullable bool List

Tags: c#, list, null, boolean

I have `List<bool> bools` and I want to insert some bool variables at specific index of it but i also want to set some indexes to null or something different than just true/false but since it's a bool list it cant be a string and the first that came to my mind was null. Once i made it a nullable `List<bool> ?bools` i was no longer able to use `bools.Insert(index,variable);` So how should i do this ?

- I want to have the index there I don't want to remove it completely

Comment: That shouldn't even compile as the `List<bool>?` would translate to `Nullable<List<bool>>` and `Nullable` will only work on non-nullable types and `List<bool>` is a nullable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `List<bool?> bools`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare you list as `List<bool?>`

```
var bools = new List<bool?>();
bools.Insert(9,false);
```

Please note that it is `.Insert(index,value)` and not the other way around.